# Does java nio read/write file actually non-blocking io?

Tags: java, nio, nonblocking

I'm learning about non-blocking i/o terms. Mainly, I'm learning java Nio. I'm trying to understand non-blocking i/o better and observe how it works in the implementation with Java Nio.

I read a dozen questions and answers related to the non-blocking i/o term and the non-blocking i/o by using java Nio.

I see a following similar statement everywhere.

> Non-blocking IO does not wait for the data to be read or written before returning. Java NIO non-blocking mode allows the thread to request writing data to a channel, but Non-blocking IO does not wait for the data to be read or written before returning.

I tried to illustrate the statement with an example java code that reads a file's content using Nio. However, the thread is still blocked at the channel's read() method.

```
System.out.println("Thread-" + Thread.currentThread().getName() 
+ "-" + Thread.currentThread().getId());// Thread-main-1

String filePath = "./resources/nio-demo.txt";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
FileChannel fileChannel = fis.getChannel();

ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(102400);

int bytesRead = fileChannel.read(buf);
System.out.println(buf.position()); //check how many bytes are written to the buf, always 102400

while (bytesRead != -1)
{

    buf.flip();

    while (buf.hasRemaining())
    {
        System.out.print((char) buf.get());
    }

    buf.clear();
    bytesRead = fileChannel.read(buf);
}
fis.close();
```

As I understand, after triggering the read() method, the thread will execute the following line of code. It doesn't matter if the buf is full of data or not.
But here, the thread is blocked until the buf is complete and continues the process sequence.

The above example reads a file about 300M with buf is 102400.

The situation confused me much; perhaps I misunderstood non-blocking i/o with java Nio.

Could you please help me explain this situation?

How does java Nio achieve purely non-blocking i/o with only one thread?

Comment: I've copied your exact snippet and tested your code with two files of 2Mb and 300Mb. In both cases the code runs properly. In the 300Mb file case the code takes significantly much more, but the thread is not blocked at the read operation. It keeps retrieving and printing what it has read. It might be something else that blocks your thread or if it's not then define  what you mean by "blocked"

Comment: FileChannel always performs *blocking* I/O, please check javadoc for java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel#read

Comment: @Dan yes, the snippet code runs properly. I expected that after executing fileChannel.read(buf), the buf does not need to be fulfilled with data and then execute the next line of code. 

For instance, the buf size is 102400, the next line of code can get executed when the buf is written some bytes (0 or less than buf size); the rest bytes can be done automatically by a non-blocking mechanism.(As my understanding)

In other words, the thread can continue working when the buf is not full of data yet.

Comment: @HienNg The documentation does not say that. It states that at every read the method will attempt to retrieve a number of bytes up to the size of the `ByteBuffer` specified, which implies anything between 0 and the buffer's size. In fact: "Bytes are read starting at this channel's current file position, and then the file position is updated **with the number of bytes actually read.** The ByteBuffer does not refill itself after the first read while the thread is performing other operations. If that was the behavior you were expecting.

Comment: @Dan yes, your last statement is what I wanted to see and made me so confused, but now I saw that I was wrong. I had no deep understanding of non-blocking with Java Nio.  I will dive deeper into java doc.
I still want to see a case that with only one thread, java can work with a non-blocking IO mechanism that only one thread can back to its work when the buf is full of data and do other work if the buf is not full yet.

Comment: @HienNg - Nonblocking does not mean "performed asynchronously." It means a method will not wait to read (or write) all the bytes you've requested, if they're not yet available (or cannot yet be received).

Comment: Trying to read between the lines, I think what you are missing is that "non-blocking I/O" usually implies selectable channels and selectors so that a single thread can process I/O from many, many channels by polling for those that are ready without blocking. The most authoritative and clear resource to study might be [the package description.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html#package.description)

Comment: @AndyThomas your comment made me confused, as you have said so it means my example is already non-blocking i/o, but actually, it doesn't.
I expected a non-blocking mechanism will not block the thread so that only one thread can perform asynchronously while i/o devices operate their work.

Comment: @AndyThomas I have tried learning the basic concept of DMA, hardware controller, I thought I understand the concept of non-blocking i/o until I try to illustrate them by coding.
Because I purely believe that if the thread does not need to wait i/o operate then it can continue working other work asynchronously.

I'm happy if you can explain more from a concept perspective.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you 'purely believe'. The read blocks. Period. Not for long, as disks are quick, unless you are reading from a network drive. Note that `SocketChannel` has a method to put it into non-blocking mode. So does `ServerSocketChannel`: `FileChannel` does not.

Answer (score 1):

> […] perhaps I misunderstood non-blocking i/o with java Nio.

Yes; it sounds like you've misunderstood what's meant by "blocking" and "non-blocking". These terms are *not* synonymous with "synchronous" and "asynchronous".

The distinction between "blocking" and "non-blocking" isn't so meaningful when reading from a regular file — and indeed, [java.nio.channels.FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) doesn't have blocking and non-blocking modes — so please put files out of your mind, and instead, imagine a situation where two processes are communicating via a channel. For example, consider a shell pipeline, where the output of one process is piped to the input of another:

```
./writer | ./reader
```

Let's imagine that the writer doesn't write continuously to the pipe, but rather, just prints every so often; maybe its output is computationally expensive to generate, or maybe its output isn't its primary work but is just a rare secondary effect (e.g., printing out a message every time it's completed a chunk of work), or . . . well, you get the idea.

Now, consider this from the perspective of the reader process, when it performs an operation like this:

```
numBytesRead = inputChannel.read(dst);
```

There are (at least) two different ways we could imagine this working:

- It might read until `dst` is full or it reaches the end of the input. This involves potentially waiting a long time for the writer process to generate enough blocks of output to fill `dst`.

  - We call this a "blocking" operation.
- It might read until `dst` is full, or it reaches the end of the input, *or* it runs out of already-available input. This doesn't involve waiting for the writer process, *but* it means that it might not fill `dst` — in fact, it might not read even a single byte into `dst` — even if there may be more input to read later.

  - We call this a "non-blocking" operation.

Does that make sense?

Another situation where "blocking" and "non-blocking" operations come up a lot is with *locks*. For example, FileChannel has both `lock` (blocking) and `tryLock` (non-blocking) methods to obtain a filesystem lock; if it's not possible to take a lock immediately, `lock` waits until it can, whereas `tryLock` just immediately returns `null`.

---

A few other things worth noting:

- Even if a channel *supports* non-blocking operations, it will still *default* to blocking ones. To get non-blocking behavior, you need to put it in "non-blocking mode", e.g. by calling its [configureBlocking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectableChannel.html#configureBlocking-boolean-) method if it has one.
- Even a "non-blocking" operation can take a long time, if the buffer is large and there's a lot of input available. It's just that it never actually *blocks*: it runs only as long as there's input available, and if at any point it catches up to the writer, it immediately returns what it's read so far.
- The NIO APIs include a class called [java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html), which behaves how you expected FileChannel to behave. It's analogous to FileChannel, except that its methods are *asynchronous*: instead of waiting for the actual read or write to *complete*, they just cause it to *start* (in a separate thread). You'll notice that its method signatures are better designed for this call pattern; instead of returning an integer, they accept a callback or return a future.